# How to get mail id of twitter account through nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, twitter

I am trying to get mail id from twitter user through nodejs at the result I only got tweets and other details of users  but I don't get mail id. I attach my code anyone tell me whether my code is write way to get mail id

```
    // twitter api script
    var config = require("./config");
// In config file I have my consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key,access_token_secret 

    var fs = require('fs');

    var Twitter = require('twitter');

    var client = new Twitter(config.twitter);

    var writer = fs.createWriteStream('tweets.json')

    var start_time = 0;

    var handles = "";



    fs.readFile('./t_handle.csv', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {

    var params = {
                    'include_email' : true
                };
        handles = contents.split("\n");
        writer.write("[");
        handles.forEach(function(handle){
            handle = handle.split("/")[3];
            if(typeof handle !== 'undefined' && handle){
                handle = handle.split("?")[0];
                get_handle_tweets(handle,params);
            }
        });
    });

    function get_handle_tweets(handle){

        client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: handle }, function(error, tweets,params,response) {

            if(error){          
                console.log(error);
            }else{

                    tweets.forEach(function(tweet){
                        writer.write(JSON.stringify(tweet)+",\n");

                    });
                                }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First check if when you Authorize for your app in the Will be able to see field, "see your email address" is there , if not check if you have valid privacy policy and TOS URL since white listing the app is no longer required, also in php I had to Change `'include_email' : true` to `'include_email' : 'true'` sometime ago when I tried this, so that could be the issue.

Comment: yes I change 'include_email' : true to 'include_email' : 'true' but still I don't get mail id